# What are pointer indices in C and what do they reference?

Tags: c, pointers, indexing

I have searched for a while now and most results didn't help a lot because almost all index and pointer related questions are headed towards arrays. I have a conceptual problem visualizing what the index of a pointer might be. This example function takes `argv[1]` from arguments:

```
unsigned long pointerfun(const char* p){
    int* ip;                    // Declare an int pointer ip
    ip = (int*)p;               // Initialize the pointer with the value of p cast to an int pointer
    int i;
    int res=0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){         // Loops from 0 to 4
        res += ip[i];           // ...incrementing res by ip[0], ip[1],...
    }
    return res;
}
```

So I realize a pointer points to a memory location, in my example code ip points to whatever memory address is entered as p. But in my understanding, pointers are no data structures, so I have no idea what `ip[0,1,...,4]` might reference to.

Would be really great if someone more prudent could illuminate me here.

Comment: You should count that as undefined behavior and not use it. Unless you know what you are doing, and If you have to ask, you don't.

Comment: Very simplified you can look at `ip` as being an array of `int` elements. In many cases arrays and pointers are interchangeable.

Comment: Also, for any array or pointer `p` and index `i` the expressions `p[i]` and `*(p + i)` are equivalent.

Comment: `ip[i]` --> `*(ip+i)`

Comment: @MariusSiuram Nope, like I said for *any* array or pointer. It's not even possible if having a `void *` as that will give a compiler error. Adding a number to a pointer (*any* pointer) will add an offset in the size of the base type. For example, for `int *` the base-type is `int` so `ip + 2` will add `2 * sizeof(int)` as byte offset.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So in this case, the res variable adds up the memory address ip is pointing to, then the memory address ip + 2 byte, ip + 4 byte, ip + 6 byte and ip + 8 byte? That means if ip points to address 100, then res will add 100+102+104+106+108?

Comment: No you're not adding the addresses in the loop, because you *dereference* the addresses by using array indexing, and dereferencing a pointer will give you the value that the address points to. So the loop adds the *values* pointed to by `ip + 1` etc. Also, there's no fixed size to `int`, it's *at least* two bytes but on modern 32- or 64-bit systems typically 4 bytes.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So since my system has an int size of 4, res collects the values from addresses ip+0, ip+4, ip+8, ip+12, ip+16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help you better understand, lets try and make it more "graphical"...

Memory is a series of consecutive locations where values can be stored. After your assignment `ip = (int*)p` you can look at `ip` like this:

```
ip
|
v
+-------+-------+-------+----
| ip[0] | ip[1] | ip[2] | ...
+-------+-------+-------+----
^       ^       ^       ^
|       |       |       |
100     104     108     112
```

Since `ip` is a pointer, there is really no specific end to the "array" it points to, the end you have to keep track of yourself.

---

Now when it comes to addressing, for simplicity's sake lets say that `ip` points to the address `100`, that means that the contents of the variable `ip` is `100`. Lets also say that `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Then when you do `ip[2]` it's the same thing as doing `*(ip + 2)`, then you are adding `2 * sizeof(int)` (i.e. `8`) as *byte* offset to the pointer, and get address `108` which is then dereferenced giving you the contents of `ip[2]` (whatever that might be).

---

Now for a little curiosity and to "really fry your noodle": Thanks to the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition), the expression `*(ip + i)` is of course the same as `*(i + ip)` which leads to the weird but valid transformation that `ip[i]` is the same as `i[ip]`.

Comment: Okay that helped a bit. If I am recalling right, the stack grows up, so these 5 addresses 100-116 from the loop are all inside of the buffer p entered at the beginning?

Comment: @AdHominem Who's to say that `ip` has to point to the stack? That a piece of memory just happens to share space with the stack doesn't matter, it's still not treated as a stack data structure. The compiler doesn't know where the argument `p` is pointing in the function you show, so it has to treat all memory and all pointer and all arrays exactly the same.

Comment: What I mean, following my example code: If you enter the char array p = 1234567890, `int* ip = (int*)p` then points to 1234567890 as a memory address?

Answer (score 1):

`ip[n]` is the same as `*(ip+n)`.

You can see `ip[n]` as the `n-th integer` away from the `integer` at address `ip`. Usually this type of syntax occurs in an array.

Also, if you did not allocate memory properly you might run into some run-time errors / invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: You mean if the buffer is not at least 20 bytes long? (5 times loop * int size)

Comment: @AdHominem I am not sure if `int` are always the same size on different systems. But if they are 4 bytes on your system, then in the example above, the 20 bytes should be allocated. Also, since you are reading the integer values, you will also need to initialize them.